# How to make Blender auto refresh external linked files?

Tags: rendering

The a .blend file in shared on OneDrive. It is in a pre-edit state and does not show changes made to it.

We are working as a team, sharing Blender files through the web, but it is impossible to work this way.

What should I do to make changes appear to my team members after editing?

Computer Specs

- Blender3.6.5
- Windows 10 Pro
- 22H2
- 2020/‎12/‎21
- OS 19045.3930
- 006918471453
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz 2.50 GHz
- RAM  4.00 GB
- x64

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Blender doesn't automatically reload external dependencies or refresh linked files on changes.

You have to manually refresh them yourself, either by:

1. Reopening the current file to force refresh dependencies
2. Going to *File > Revert* (be sure to save your changes first)
3. Or opening an *Outliner*, changing to *Blender File* mode from the header, and right-clicking any linked file and choosing *Reload*.

[image]

Alternatively install the addon [Auto Reload Linked Libraries](https://github.com/gandalf3/auto-reload-linked-libraries) by [Gandalf3](https://github.com/gandalf3) to have Blender do it automatically for you.

> ### Auto Reload Linked Libraries
>
> A simple Blender addon which auto-reloads linked library .blend files
> when it detects that they have been modified.
>
> ### Usage
>
> This addon doesn't have a UI. Once it's enabled, linked libraries
> should just refresh automatically.